# How to convert Rhapsody models to respective simulink models

Tags: matlab, simulink, rhapsody

Looking for guidance in a problem i am facing.
I have one a project in Rhapsody which i needed in Matlab Simulink.
I tried manually in creating a new project from scratch in Simulink and i succeeded.
But I got a few other Projects in converting the same.
Is there any mechanism we can do using a third party ( atleast) in integrating a rhapsody model into its respective simulink models.

Not looking for a direct solution, but any approaches in starting this.

What I did so far:

- Looked into Rhapsody Project - plugin methods:  No idea how to start
- Looked into Matlab Project - mscript methods: No idea how to start

Comment: Do you need to do a full conversion, or just run existing Rhapsody functionality within Simulink?  If the latter then [Creating Simulink S-functions by using Rational Rhapsody](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSB2MU_8.3.1/com.ibm.rhp.integ.designtools.doc/topics/rhp_t_int_creating_simulink_s_functions.html) is the easiest approach.

Comment: @Phil Goddard : Thanks for the support. What I am looking for is the complete conversion. Is that possible!

Comment: I'm unaware of any automated tool.